# Target-typing in modern C++

Tags: c++

When I say target-typing I mean using the type of the receiver variable or parameter as information to infer parts of the code I'm assigning to it. Like for example, in C# you'd write something like this to pass a nullable value or a `null` (empty) if necessary:

```cs
void f(int? i) {}
void caller(bool b) => 
    f(b ? 5 : null);  // value is bound to an int? parameter so all information 
                      // to build this object is already in code
```

The best I could come up with in C++ is something like this:

```cpp
void f(const optional<int>& i) {}
void caller(bool b)
{
    f(b ? make_optional(5) : optional<int>());
}
```

And it works, but it requires me to write `optional` twice and provide the optional type once, even though all the information should already be in code. This is, in my humble opinion, what type inference should do for you without having to repeat yourself multiple times per line. And because the following does work:

```cpp
optional<int> i;
i = {};  // empty
i = {5}; // a value
```

I'd have thought that the next logical step would also work:

```cpp
void f(const optional<int>& i) {}
void caller(bool b)
{
    f(b ? {5} : {});  // doesn't compile
}
```

So overall from various experiments it seems target-typing works when directly assigning a value to a variable, but not as part of a ternary conditional expression bound to a parameter? Am I understanding this correctly? There is no limit on the C++ version, I've been writing this in MS C++20 for instance.

And a related question, though not the main focus of my question, is there a better way of writing an `optional<>` initialization that can either have a value or not based on a boolean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++, expressions have types.

`{}` is not, however, an expression.  There are a handful of restricted contexts where `{}` could be used when you'd expect an expression should go there.  This doesn't make `{}` into an expression.

`?:` is an operation, and its arguments must have types.  The type of `?:` is derived from the type of its 2 arguments (the rules are complex, but it tries to find a common type).

```
b ? std::optional{5} : std::nullopt;
```

is similar to what you want.  Here, the fact that `std::nullopt` can convert to a `std::optional<int>` is used to deduce the type of `?:` expression.

You can also write:

```
template<class T>
std::optional<std::decay_t<T>> maybe( bool b, T&& t ) {
  if (!b) return std::nullopt;
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

which lets you write

```
maybe( b, 5 )
```

for your case.

Fancier things can be done, where you use `template<class T> operator T()` on a type to deduce the type you are returning into.

But, in general, the C++ type system goes one way.

Comment: Oooh, I do like `b ? optional{5} : nullopt`, but it implies the need to write a bunch of helper objects (`nullopt` and the non-generic looking `optional`) as a work around. As a consumer of the library it's fine, but that's a pain to write as a library producer.

Comment: @Blindy You don't need to write anything. `nullopt` is standard and the "non generic" `optional` is just using C++17 class template deduction rules

Comment: "nullopt is standard" no it's not, a human being sat down and wrote code to give you `nullopt`. If I wasn't clear what "library producer" means, that's the guy who wrote `nullopt`. As to why that's just a workaround, it gives you nothing a simple `optional<int>()` would give you, you just don't have to type it again. Target-typing would have taken care of that at the compiler level.

Comment: @Blindy "a human being sat down and wrote code to give you nullopt"  some humans write code on a standing desk ... 

Comment: @Blindy So `nullopt` is not the same type as `nullptr`.  `std::optional` **intentionally** does not convert `nullptr` to a null value, because a `std::optional` could store a type that could be initialized from a `nullptr`.  `nullopt` is conceptually the type of thing the `optional` stores when it stores nothing (ie, `optional<T>` is an asymmetric sum type of nullopt and `T`)

Comment: I understand that, yeah. I don't believe I said anything about `nullptr` on this entire page, but I understand.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont "*So `nullopt` is not the same type as `nullptr`*" - it is also not the same type as `std::optional`, either.  It is a separate type (a `struct`) which a `std::optional` can be constructed from, as `std::optional` has an overloaded constructor that accepts `std::nullopt_t` as input.

Answer (score 0):

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont already gave the fully fledged answer, so I'll just give the short one, your code can work if you switch the short version, ternary operator condition, with a full if statement:

```
void f(optional<int> i) {}
void caller(bool b)
{
    if (b) {
        f(5);
    }
    else {
        f({});
    }
}
```

Comment: Not useful, I have 6 different maybe-optionals I send to a constructor as parameters.